# qtum-core build issue when compiling with OpenSSL

Tags: c++, c, makefile, openssl, ubuntu-14.04

I am getting an error trying to build qtum-core. The error is:

```
make
...

  CXX      libbitcoin_common_a-key.o
key.cpp: In function ‘bool EnsureLowS(std::vector<unsigned char>&)’:
key.cpp:149:19: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘ECDSA_SIG {aka struct ECDSA_SIG_st}’
     if (BN_cmp(sig->s, halforder) > 0) {
                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ecdsa.h:10:0,
                 from key.cpp:17:
/usr/include/openssl/ec.h:1039:16: error: forward declaration of ‘ECDSA_SIG {aka struct ECDSA_SIG_st}’
 typedef struct ECDSA_SIG_st ECDSA_SIG;
                ^
key.cpp:151:19: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘ECDSA_SIG {aka struct ECDSA_SIG_st}’
         BN_sub(sig->s, order, sig->s);
                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ecdsa.h:10:0,
                 from key.cpp:17:
/usr/include/openssl/ec.h:1039:16: error: forward declaration of ‘ECDSA_SIG {aka struct ECDSA_SIG_st}’
 typedef struct ECDSA_SIG_st ECDSA_SIG;
                ^
key.cpp:151:34: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘ECDSA_SIG {aka struct ECDSA_SIG_st}’
         BN_sub(sig->s, order, sig->s);
                                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ecdsa.h:10:0,
                 from key.cpp:17:
/usr/include/openssl/ec.h:1039:16: error: forward declaration of ‘ECDSA_SIG {aka struct ECDSA_SIG_st}’
 typedef struct ECDSA_SIG_st ECDSA_SIG;
                ^
make[2]: *** [libbitcoin_common_a-key.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/qtum_data/qtum/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qtum_data/qtum/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

---

1. `git clone --recursive https://github.com/qtumproject/qtum.git`
2. `cd qtum`
3. Run `autogen`

   ```
   ./autogen.sh
   libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, `build-aux'.
   libtoolize: copying file `build-aux/ltmain.sh'
   libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `build-aux/m4'.
   libtoolize: copying file `build-aux/m4/libtool.m4'
   libtoolize: copying file `build-aux/m4/ltoptions.m4'
   libtoolize: copying file `build-aux/m4/ltsugar.m4'
   libtoolize: copying file `build-aux/m4/ltversion.m4'
   ...
   configure.ac:32: installing 'build-aux/missing'
   Makefile.am:12: warning: user variable 'GZIP_ENV' defined here ...
   /usr/share/automake-1.14/am/distdir.am: ... overrides Automake variable 'GZIP_ENV' defined here
   src/Makefile.am: installing 'build-aux/depcomp'
   src/Makefile.am:703: warning: user target '.mm.o' defined here ...
   /usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am: ... overrides Automake target '.mm.o' defined here
   parallel-tests: installing 'build-aux/test-driver'
   ```
4. Configure

   ```
   ./configure --without-gui
   checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
   checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
   checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
   checking whether build environment is sane... yes
   checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
   checking for gawk... no
   checking for mawk... mawk
   checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
   checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
   checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
   checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
   checking for g++... g++
   ...

   configure: Using jni: no
   configure: ******
   configure: WARNING: experimental build
   configure: Experimental features do not have stable APIs or properties, and may not be safe for production use.
   configure: Building ECDH module: yes
   configure: ******
   checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
   configure: creating ./config.status
   config.status: creating Makefile
   config.status: creating libsecp256k1.pc
   config.status: creating src/libsecp256k1-config.h
   config.status: executing depfiles commands
   config.status: executing libtool commands
   Fixing libtool for -rpath problems.

   Options used to compile and link:
     with wallet   = yes
     with gui / qt = no
     with zmq      = no
     with test     = yes
     with bench    = yes
     with upnp     = auto
     debug enabled = no
     werror        = no

     target os     = linux
     build os      =

     CC            = gcc
     CFLAGS        = -g -O2
     CPPFLAGS      =  -DQTUM_BUILD -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
     CXX           = g++ -std=c++11
     CXXFLAGS      = -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wvla -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unknown-pragmas
     LDFLAGS       =
   ```
5. Make

   ```
   make    
   Making all in src
   make[1]: Entering directory `/home/qtum_data/qtum/src'
   make[2]: Entering directory `/home/qtum_data/qtum/src'
     CXX      crypto/libbitcoinconsensus_la-aes.lo
     CXX      crypto/libbitcoinconsensus_la-chacha20.lo
     CXX      crypto/libbitcoinconsensus_la-hmac_sha256.lo
     CXX      crypto/libbitcoinconsensus_la-hmac_sha512.lo
     CXX      crypto/libbitcoinconsensus_la-ripemd160.lo
     CXX      crypto/libbitcoinconsensus_la-sha1.lo
     CXX      crypto/libbitcoinconsensus_la-sha256.lo
     CXX      crypto/libbitcoinconsensus_la-sha512.lo
     CC       cpp-ethereum/utils/libscrypt/libbitcoinconsensus_la-b64.lo
     CC       cpp-ethereum/utils/libscrypt/libbitcoinconsensus_la-crypto-mcf.lo
     CC       cpp-ethereum/utils/libscrypt/libbitcoinconsensus_la-crypto_scrypt-check.lo
     CC       cpp-ethereum/utils/libscrypt/libbitcoinconsensus_la-crypto_scrypt-hash.lo
     CC       cpp-ethereum/utils/libscrypt/libbitcoinconsensus_la-crypto_scrypt-hexconvert.lo
     CC       cpp-ethereum/utils/libscrypt/libbitcoinconsensus_la-crypto_scrypt-nosse.lo
     CC       cpp-ethereum/utils/libscrypt/libbitcoinconsensus_la-crypto-scrypt-saltgen.lo
     CC       cpp-ethereum/utils/libscrypt/libbitcoinconsensus_la-sha256.lo
     CC       cpp-ethereum/utils/libscrypt/libbitcoinconsensus_la-slowequals.lo
     CXX      libbitcoinconsensus_la-arith_uint256.lo
     CXX      consensus/libbitcoinconsensus_la-merkle.lo
     CXX      libbitcoinconsensus_la-hash.lo
     CXX      primitives/libbitcoinconsensus_la-block.lo
     CXX      primitives/libbitcoinconsensus_la-transaction.lo
     CXX      libbitcoinconsensus_la-pubkey.lo
     CXX      script/libbitcoinconsensus_la-bitcoinconsensus.lo
     CXX      script/libbitcoinconsensus_la-interpreter.lo
     CXX      script/libbitcoinconsensus_la-script.lo
     CXX      script/libbitcoinconsensus_la-script_error.lo
     CXX      libbitcoinconsensus_la-uint256.lo
     CXX      libbitcoinconsensus_la-utilstrencodings.lo
   make[3]: Entering directory `/home/qtum_data/qtum/src/secp256k1'
   gcc -I. -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-function -c src/gen_context.c -o gen_context.o
   gcc gen_context.o -o gen_context
   ./gen_context
     CC       src/libsecp256k1_la-secp256k1.lo
     CCLD     libsecp256k1.la
   make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/qtum_data/qtum/src/secp256k1'
     CXXLD    libbitcoinconsensus.la
   copying selected object files to avoid basename conflicts...
     CXX      qtumd-bitcoind.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-addrman.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-addrdb.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-bloom.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-blockencodings.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-chain.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-checkpoints.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-httprpc.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-httpserver.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-init.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-dbwrapper.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-merkleblock.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-miner.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-net.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-net_processing.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-noui.o
     CXX      policy/libbitcoin_server_a-fees.o
     CXX      policy/libbitcoin_server_a-policy.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-pow.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-pos.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-rest.o
     CXX      rpc/libbitcoin_server_a-blockchain.o
     CXX      rpc/libbitcoin_server_a-mining.o
     CXX      rpc/libbitcoin_server_a-misc.o
     CXX      rpc/libbitcoin_server_a-net.o
     CXX      rpc/libbitcoin_server_a-rawtransaction.o
     CXX      rpc/libbitcoin_server_a-server.o
     CXX      script/libbitcoin_server_a-sigcache.o
     CXX      script/libbitcoin_server_a-ismine.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-timedata.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-torcontrol.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-txdb.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-txmempool.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-ui_interface.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-validation.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-validationinterface.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-versionbits.o
     CXX      qtum/libbitcoin_server_a-qtumstate.o
     CXX      qtum/libbitcoin_server_a-qtumtransaction.o
     CXX      qtum/libbitcoin_server_a-qtumDGP.o
     CXX      consensus/libbitcoin_server_a-consensus.o
     CXX      qtum/libbitcoin_server_a-storageresults.o
     AR       libbitcoin_server.a
     CXX      libbitcoin_common_a-amount.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_common_a-base58.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_common_a-chainparams.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_common_a-coins.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_common_a-compressor.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_common_a-core_read.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_common_a-core_write.o
     CXX      libbitcoin_common_a-key.o
   key.cpp: In function ‘bool EnsureLowS(std::vector<unsigned char>&)’:
   key.cpp:149:19: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘ECDSA_SIG {aka struct ECDSA_SIG_st}’
        if (BN_cmp(sig->s, halforder) > 0) {
                      ^
   In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ecdsa.h:10:0,
                    from key.cpp:17:
   /usr/include/openssl/ec.h:1039:16: error: forward declaration of ‘ECDSA_SIG {aka struct ECDSA_SIG_st}’
    typedef struct ECDSA_SIG_st ECDSA_SIG;
                   ^
   key.cpp:151:19: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘ECDSA_SIG {aka struct ECDSA_SIG_st}’
            BN_sub(sig->s, order, sig->s);
                      ^
   In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ecdsa.h:10:0,
                    from key.cpp:17:
   /usr/include/openssl/ec.h:1039:16: error: forward declaration of ‘ECDSA_SIG {aka struct ECDSA_SIG_st}’
    typedef struct ECDSA_SIG_st ECDSA_SIG;
                   ^
   key.cpp:151:34: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘ECDSA_SIG {aka struct ECDSA_SIG_st}’
            BN_sub(sig->s, order, sig->s);
                                     ^
   In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ecdsa.h:10:0,
                    from key.cpp:17:
   /usr/include/openssl/ec.h:1039:16: error: forward declaration of ‘ECDSA_SIG {aka struct ECDSA_SIG_st}’
    typedef struct ECDSA_SIG_st ECDSA_SIG;
                   ^
   make[2]: *** [libbitcoin_common_a-key.o] Error 1
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/qtum_data/qtum/src'
   make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
   make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qtum_data/qtum/src'
   make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
   ```
6. my server Environment

   OS - Linux xxxxxxx-X10SLL-F 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
   openssl version - OpenSSL 1.0.2g
7. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>   CXX      libbitcoin_common_a-key.o
> key.cpp: In function ‘bool EnsureLowS(std::vector<unsigned char>&)’:
> key.cpp:149:19: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘ECDSA_SIG {aka struct ECDSA_SIG_st}’
>      if (BN_cmp(sig->s, halforder) > 0) {
>                    ^
> ```

It looks like your machine has OpenSSL 1.1.0 locally, but the qtum-core is written for OpenSSL 1.0.2. That's because of the *`incomplete type ECDSA_SIG`* error. OpenSSL 1.1.0 made a bunch of things private in OpenSSL 1.1.0 that used to be public and accessible in OpenSSL 1.0.2.

You can do two things. First, downgrade to OpenSSL 1.0.2 so qtum-core can access the data members again.

Second, you can upgrade qtum-core to a version that is OpenSSL 1.1.0 aware. If qtum-core is not OpenSSL 1.1.0 aware, then file a bug report to let the authors know about the problem.

The problem you are asking about may be [Qtum Issue 382](https://github.com/qtumproject/qtum/issues/382). If so, then it looks like your only choice is Option (1), downgrade to OpenSSL 1.0.2.

---

Here is how to configure with a different OpenSSL (i.e., a different on than the one from a distribution).

```
$ git clone https://github.com/qtumproject/qtum.git
$ cd qtum/
$ autoreconf -f -i
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, 'build-aux'.
libtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'build-aux/m4'.
libtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
...
```

Here is the important part, before running make:

```
$ ./configure --help | grep -i -E 'ssl|crypto'
  SSL_CFLAGS  C compiler flags for SSL, overriding pkg-config
  SSL_LIBS    linker flags for SSL, overriding pkg-config
  CRYPTO_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for CRYPTO, overriding pkg-config
  CRYPTO_LIBS linker flags for CRYPTO, overriding pkg-config
```

There are no `--with-XXX` options to control OpenSSL, but it can be picked up through `pkg-config`. So...

I install upgrades in `/usr/local`. Headers are in `/usr/local/include`, and libraries are in `/usr/local/lib64` (because it is Fedora). The local version of OpenSSL is 1.0.2:

```
$ cat /usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib64
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenSSL-libssl
Description: Secure Sockets Layer and cryptography libraries
Version: 1.0.2n
Requires.private: libcrypto
Libs: -L${libdir} -lssl
Libs.private: -Wl,-R,/usr/local/lib64 -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -ldl
Cflags: -I${includedir}

$ cat /usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib64
includedir=${prefix}/include
enginesdir=${libdir}/engines

Name: OpenSSL-libcrypto
Description: OpenSSL cryptography library
Version: 1.0.2n
Requires:
Libs: -L${libdir} -lcrypto
Libs.private: -Wl,-R,/usr/local/lib64 -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -ldl
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

I am ready to build. The next step is (`--disable-wallet` because I don't feel like fixing the Autools errors):

```
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/ ./configure --disable-wallet
configure: loading site script /usr/local/share/config.site
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/local/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/local/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
...
checking for dynamic linked boost test... yes
checking for mismatched boost c++11 scoped enums... ok
checking for SSL... yes
checking for CRYPTO... yes
...
```

---

Related, I have some scripts to install OpenSSL and some other programs at [Noloader | Build-Scripts](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts). Clone the repo, then run:

```
./build-cacerts.sh  # install CA's needed for Wget downloads
./build-openssl.sh  # download, build and install OpenSSL in /usr/local
```

I use the build scripts for downlevel clients, like Fedora 7 and Solaris 10. You don't have to use the build scripts. But you do need to get a copy of OpenSSL 1.0.2 installed locally.